# IntelliJ Angular project throwing TSLINT error for HTML files in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, tslint

What steps will reproduce the issue?

1. Create Angular project in IntelliJ via angular-cli (version 1.5)
2. Open the same project in WebStorm; open any of the HTML files.
3. It will throw TSLINT error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Angular and Typescript version do you use? Looks similar to [WEB-30045](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30045), caused by lack of TypeScript 2.6 support in Angular (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20146)

Another related problem is https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18322

Comment: typescript version is 2.4.2. Do I also need to enable the -expirementalDecorator ?

Comment: I am currently using typescript 2.6.2 version. My webstorm version is 2017.3 - still the errors are not going. Can I upgrade my typescript?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18322 is planned to be fixed in Typescript 2.7

Answer (score -1):

WebStorm TypeScript version should match the one used by Angular. The version of TypeScript used by Angular is set in

> package.json

To do so, select

> Prefereces... > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript

and then, from the TypeScript dropdown, select the *node_modules* TypeScript installation instead of "Bundled".

Click OK and restart WebStorm.